# Changing the 'Server Collation' after installation

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, collation

I want to change the Server Collation of SQL Server 2008 R2

As all opinions says (including MSDN) the following command should be executed:

> E:\setup.exe /q /ACTION=RebuildDatabase /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER /SAPWD=”******″ /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=”HEREISMYPROBLEM” /SqlCollation=SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

As I Pointed, my problem is with the SYSADMINACCOUNT paremeter because the error that I get is:

> The Windows account ”blablabla” does not exist and cannot be provisioned as a SQL Server system administrator.

I tried all possible windows accounts that may be, but It's not working.
Please can you guide me how to know my correct windows account.

The MSDN link that shows this problem is
[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179254.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207003.aspx) describes the switches and says to use "DOMAIN\User" format, for example:

```
BUILTIN\Administrators MyDomain\MyUser
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that gets stuck with this problem and cant find an answer. The commands work you just need to run cmd as an administrator for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this batch file for [change collation on SQL Server 2008](https://github.com/AmirNBA9/SQLAssistant/blob/master/Admin/BatchFiles/ChangeCollationFor2008R2-2012.bat)

1. But you need edit batch file for set you instance and target collation.
2. Stop SQL Server Service when you run this file
3. File need Run as administrator

- If don't work well (maybe access problem), you can use cmd (Run as admin) and run batch file steps on cmd